# How can I compensate for a removed element in an array iteration that is still in progress?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am iterating over an array of strings using forEach(), and testing each element's length to determine wether it is even or odd. If the length of the string is even, it will be removed using splice().

My input and output are shown below, and as you can see even though (i think) my conditions are correct, in my return array, I still get an even, two character word - which should have been spliced out.

Code:

```js
function filterOddLengthWords(words) {
    words.forEach(function(element, index) {
        if (element.length%2===0) {
            words.splice(index, 1);
        }
    })
    return words;
}

var output = filterOddLengthWords(['there', 'it', 'is', 'now']);
console.log(output); // --> [ 'there', 'is', 'now' ]
```

I understand where the error is, but I just don't know how to compensate for it. I could possibly rewrite this by creating an empty array at the beginning of the function, and then testing each element against the inverse condition, using the push() method to add each positive to the empty array. However, that is more inefficient and I'm curious to see if my way is possible. Thanks for the answers in advance.

Comment: Use `.filter` instead: `words => words.filter(el => el.length % 2 === 0)`

Comment: What do the arrows here represent?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions A more concise way of writing functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By splicing an array, you change the index, but `forEach` takes the elements in advance and the old indices.

Usually by using `splice`, the iteration is started from the end and if some item is remoce, the index remains for the items before.

---

You could filter the array.

```js
function filterOddLengthWords(words) {
    return words.filter(function(element) {
        return element.length % 2;
    });
}

var output = filterOddLengthWords(['there', 'it', 'is', 'now']);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Ok I didn't know this existed, thanks. How did you instantly remember what function to use? Would you say that comes from experience?

Comment: no. it is deterministic. for example, if you need only one item use `find`, some item use `filter`, check some condition for just one use `some` the same for all use `every` and if you need a new array for each item take `map`. and only for iterating take `forEach`.

Comment: _Write a function called "getLengthOfLongestElement".

Given an array, "getLengthOfLongestElement" returns the length of the longest string in the given array._     

    
So, if you don't mind, what would be your thoughts on how to approach this?

Comment: that is a good example for `reduce`, because you need a value, which needs to visit all elements and return a dependent value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with splicing the array in the `forEach()` is that when you `splice()` on the array at index 1 which has the element ***`it`*** the element at index 2 ***`is`*** is moved to index 1.

So in the next iteration when the index is 2 in the callback the element at the index 2 of the array is the value ***`now`*** instead of the element ***`is`***. As ***`now`*** is odd it is kept but the element ***`is`*** is completely skipped.

Using `Array.prototype.filter` will work here as it does not modify the original array but instead collects the valid results into a new array.